# How add value to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a short question. I need add value in all input on page, but it value not save. This is my code:

```
$('.formInput').val('1')
```

How I can input value and save result?

Comment: what you mean by ___not save___?

Comment: after update page all values is missing, but if I add it myself, then save

Comment: are you using ajax to save when updated content?

Comment: then trigger the event using `trigger()` , eg: `$('.formInput').val('1').trigger('change')`

Comment: Yes, ajax is using. But do not working with trigger. Maybe there are other options?

Comment: on which event are you using ajax??

Comment: Post some more code so that we can point out the exact problem

Comment: I understand, about trigget, maybe it have another name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? I don't clearly about "**How I can input value and save result?**".
I hope it can help you :)

```js
$('.formInput').val('1')
var value = $('.formInput').val();
$('.getValue').click(function(){
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input class="formInput" type="text" />
<input type="submit" class="getValue" value="Get Value" />
</form>
```